# Glitches and Graphical Errors

Tags: pc, guitar-hero-3

In Guitar Hero III on the PC, I am getting some weird bugs.

On my guitar background, there is blackness and visual errors. Stuttering also happens occasionally, but I could probably figure that out.

I installed Patch 1.3.1, which got the game to initially work, but those errors happen. Is it because I have too modern hardware or playing the game in 4K? Is there a compatibility settings I could try?

Comment: Is your screen-PC connection analog ? Blue VGA connector ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев I am using a Mini DisplayPort to Full DisplayPort to my GTX 1080.

Comment: Setting the controls to Keyboard/Mouse default fixes the Whammy bar and Star Power, and fixes the weird notes (presumably from having the Whammy bar down).

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: You could try using a remote control program to look at your screen and make sure it's not because of the connection to the screen.

Comment: @RobRose Windows 10-64 Bit, Fall Creator's Update.

Comment: @Camouflaged Cow Did you try the remote access? I use Chrome Remote Desktop on my Android phone for that. It doesn't even change Aero settings and so on, so that doesn't influence it.

Comment: Btw, it might help to add specs like graphics card type, game version and so on. The more, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the resolution will fix the graphical errors.

1080p and under = No Errors

1440p = A couple of errors

4K (2160p) = A lot of errors

Adjusting the resolution to be 1080p or under will fix it. The stuttering seemed to go away for me when adjusting the resolution too.

As long as Patch 1.3.1 is installed and your resolution is 1080p or under, it should be a great experience.